Asynchronous Path Limits
few Questions

How many async flows can be triggered in a single transaction? it doesn't seem to be using future/queueable limits or any other limit as far as I can see?
When pulling limits I can see async limits 12mb heap etc but I can still launch queables and futures?
I assume standard bulkification (up to 200 in one go?)

